# Can I always create new instance of IHttpClientFactory even I can use instance twice or more?

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

I wrote a WebAPI in .NET Core and used IHttpClientFactory for creating httpClients. I customized it on Startup.cs in ConfigurationServices.

```
services.AddHttpClient("ITSMServiceClient", m =>
            {
                m.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                m.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            }).SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
            {
                var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
                    UseCookies = false
                };

                // Отключаем проверку валидности http-сертификата (если необходимо)
                handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
                handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                               (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => true;

                return handler;
            });
```

Then I use it in one dataProvider via DI.

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

        public ExecuteDataProvider(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        }
```

I use methods of this provider for all sending requests

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            using (var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("ITSMServiceClient"))
            {
                return await client.SendAsync(request);
            }
        }
```

And I have a question. Is it normal behavior always get new instance from _clientFactory even if I can reuse instance twice or more in code?
All my dataProvider and another entyties describe like SingleInstance in DI.

```
builder.RegisterType<ExecuteDataProvider>().As<IExecuteDataProvider>().SingleInstance();
```

Now I use it something like this:

```
var request = CreatePostRequest(url, parameters, jParameters, checkingToken);

HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await _executeCoreDataProvider.PostAsync(request);
if (await CheckingForUnauthorizedToken(httpResponseMessage, checkingToken))
{
        request = CreatePostRequest(url, parameters, jParameters, checkingToken);
        httpResponseMessage = await _executeCoreDataProvider.PostAsync(request);
}
response = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
httpResponseMessage.Dispose();
```

And I worry about twice getting HttpClient. Is it normal or use one instance of client will be more correctly?

I've already read about ClientFactory on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests); [this](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore), and also some other sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the scope of a single request, it's normal to use just one `HttpClient`. However, if it's easier, you can get multiple instances from the `IHttpClientFactory`. The `HttpClient` itself is just a thin wrapper, so multiple instances don't have a big impact. The important part is that these instances are coming from the `IHttpClientFactory`, which shares the `HttpMessageHandler` between multiple `HttpClient` instances.

The only unusual part to your code is the `using` statement; generally, `HttpClient` instances are not disposed (this is still true in the `IHttpClientFactory` world). But this disposal isn't *bad*; just a bit unusual.

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#httpclient-and-lifetime-management

Comment: Thank you Stephen! I've thought the same, but I really had to heard an opinion.

Comment: [Updated link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#httpclient-and-lifetime-management)
"HttpClient instances can generally be treated as .NET objects **not** requiring disposal. Disposal cancels outgoing requests and guarantees the given HttpClient instance can't be used after calling Dispose. IHttpClientFactory tracks and disposes resources used by HttpClient instances"